# GCloud Coud SQL Postgres: "ERROR: permission denied for table <table>"

Tags: postgresql, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I have a postgres database in Google Cloud SQL which was created by the user "api". Now I would like to read some of the data on that database using my own user. I can connect to the database but when I run

```
SELECT * FROM data;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for table data
```

---

EDIT

I tried `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE website TO sev;` but that didn't work. The SQL defining the databse looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE website
    WITH 
    OWNER = cloudsqlsuperuser
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF8'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

GRANT ALL ON DATABASE website TO cloudsqlsuperuser;

GRANT TEMPORARY, CONNECT ON DATABASE website TO PUBLIC;

GRANT ALL ON DATABASE website TO sev;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GRANT` must be run by the owning user `api`.

Granting privileges on the database is not enough. To access a table, you must have privileges on the table itself as well as privileges on the schema that contains the table.

Comment: I tried this but that did not work either, I have amended my original question to show what the db looks like now.

Comment: But how come the "api" user has access given there is no line `GRANT ALL ... TO api` and the OWNER IS "cloudsqlsuperuser". To me it seems that there is some other way to achieve this...

Comment: `api` is the user that created the table, so it automatically gets permissions.

Comment: Is it possible to see the permissions that `api` has somehow? I checked \du and both `api` and `sev` are members of the `cloudsqlsuperuser` group which is the owner of the database. I would have thought that the permissions `api` has come from that but that would not explain why `sev` does not have them

Comment: Your though was wrong. Go ahead and grant those privileges!

Comment: This works - I would still be interested to understand how the `api` user gets it's privileges - where is this recorded?

Comment: In the access control list of the table. Have a look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html).